# why blockhash is returning the same value?

Tags: blockhash

I have been trying to learn about `blockhash` in Solidity, I have made search about it and still I cant get it. I deployed two contracts on Polygon Mumbai by using Remix. One of them is with block number 30876918, the other one with 30876932, but their `blockhash` is the same (`0x2f2e26204a8fa4569f3f3efe3932aaca31a6f3d61d631fe90be5cdcf459e26bd`).

Do you know why?

```
blockhash(uint blockNumber) returns (bytes32): hash of the 
given block when blocknumber is one of the 256 most recent blocks; otherwise returns zero
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to redo the "experiment" on Ethereum Testnet Goerli. It sounds very strange to me and I would expect to have a different result on Goerli. Please give a response with the result if you try it on Goerli.

Answer (score 1):

blockhash gives you the hash of the block within which the transaction has been processed.

So if you are calling blockhash in some function that is not a constructor, it will give you the current block hash.

*If this is not the root of your problem, share your contract and transactions, so we can give some more insight.*

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. `blockhash` takes `block.number` as parameter. And when I was calling the functions to get the `blockhash` on two different contracts, I was doing it one after another, without waiting. And that means both function calls were included in the same block and consequently they both had the same `block.number` and consequently same `blockhash`

My mistake was not to realize that `block.number` in `getBlock` and `getBlockhash` functions could be different. Thank you for your answers. And here my contracts for reference.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.8.7;

contract Blockhash1 {

    uint256 FACTOR = 57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968;

    function getBlock1() external view returns(uint) {
        return block.number;
    }

    function getBlockHash1() external view returns(bytes32) {
        return blockhash(block.number-1);
    }

    function getHashNumber1() external view returns(uint256) {
        return uint256(blockhash(block.number-1));
    }


    function getDivision1() external view returns(uint256) {
        uint256 coinFlip = uint256(blockhash(block.number-1)) / FACTOR;
        return coinFlip;
    }
}
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.8.7;

contract Blockhash2 {

    uint256 FACTOR = 57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968;

    function getBlock2() external view returns(uint) {
        return block.number;
    }

    function getBlockHash2() external view returns(bytes32) {
        return blockhash(block.number-1);
    }

    function getHashNumber2() external view returns(uint256) {
        return uint256(blockhash(block.number-1));
    }

    function getDivision2() external view returns(uint256) {
        uint256 coinFlip = uint256(blockhash(block.number-1)) / FACTOR;
        return coinFlip;
    }
}
```